# PHPMailer Contact form doesn't work on server, but does on localhost?

Tags: php, forms, server, phpmailer

I have a PHPMailer Contact Form that sends data to a a GMail account. It does this successfully when the site is operated on localhost, but I get the following error when I've uploaded the webpage to a server and tried to use the contact form: Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

I am uploading the files through Plesk to the server, though I doubt that's relevant. Here's the code:

```
<form action="currentFile.php" method="POST">
Full Name:<input required type="text" name="fullname"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                
$mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com';                 
$mail->Password = 'pass';                          
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                             
$mail->Port = 587;                                    

$mail->addAddress('mail@gmail.com');     

$mail->Subject = 'Contact Form';
$mail->Body    = "Test";
$mail->AltBody = "Test";

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

I believe changing `$mail->isSMTP();`  to `$mail->isMAIL();` makes no difference. What could I do so that the form data is sent to the email when the site is online (on my server)?

Note: The gmail account and password used are meant to be "fake" in the code below. I do intend to to target a GMail account and I have put in the Google Mail address and password successfully, hence the script running successfully on localhost.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that port 587 is open (to outgoing connections) in your server?

Comment: @Dekel I am leasing the server from a company, is this something I need to contact them about? I have tried using Port 25 and Port 465, GMail's alternative options, they also didn't work on the server. Meanwhile, 25 and 587 work just fine on localhost.

Comment: No if its a leased server you should have root access to open a port in the firewall. The method of which will vary dependant on the installed OS, control panel etc. For instance ubuntu uses ufw, any OS with WHM/Cpanel installed should be able to install CSF (ConfigServerFirewall) which is accessible through the WHM panel

Comment: @H3ll0 why are you using a form with an input if you're not going to use its value to process it? Btw, the action `action="currentFile.php"` belongs in `<form>` not input and using either a GET/POST method. Pretty sure that's what the solution is here, or least a very big part of it.

Comment: Follow the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide. It will tell you what's being blocked. I expect it's your hosting company blocking outbound mail - it's very common.

Comment: There should also be a valid `From` (email), otherwise your mailout may be treated as spam or rejected altogether.

Comment: @Chris I just allowed Port 578 on my server control panel. Unfortunately no difference was made.

Comment: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I've heard its common too. Either im lucky and have never found a host that does (i've used a few and even did a little reseller hosting in my day) or its actually not quite as common as people think. In any case more often than not these sorts of things are a precaution and as long as you provide a valid reason for wanting the port access then i don't see why they would deny it. If they do, you can always move your hosting provider they are plentiful. just ask the question about the ports before you sign up.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks this helped resolve my issue. Please post as an answer so I can give credit.

Comment: @H3ll0 You're welcome.

Comment: @H3ll0 I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"@Fred-ii- Thanks this helped resolve my issue. Please post as an answer so I can give credit. – H3ll0 10 mins ago"*

The action `action="currentFile.php"` belongs in `<form>`, not input and using either a GET/POST method.

You also need to use either method and assign/use an array for the input.

I.e.:

```
$var = $_POST['var']; // or $_GET depending on the preferred method.
```

There should also be a `From:` in the header, since that could send your mailout to spam or rejected altogether.

I.e.:

```
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
```

Reference links to troubleshoot:

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Here is the github for PHPMailer:

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

---

If you don't have an SPF record (Sender Policy Framework), creating one would be beneficial.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework
- http://www.openspf.org/

Comment: The answer was actually GMail related, found that out using debugging. Was influenced to add debugging due to your links provided, thank you.

Comment: @H3ll0 Right on, glad to hear the matter was resolved, *cheers*